# How to count rows where condition is false Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `NUM` column, I try to filter rows where column `NUM` is valid (true) and:

1. Update current dataframe
2. Insert count of wrong rows into dict `report`

I try this:

```
report["NUM"] =  dataset['NUM'].apply(~isValid).count()
```

So, it does not work for me.
Dataframe is:

```
NUM AGE COUNTRY
1   18  USA
2   19  USA
3   30  AU
```

The `isValid` it is a function

```
def isValid(value):
   return True
```

Remark:

I use this rule:

```
report["NUM"] =  (~dataset['NUM'].apply(checkNumber)).sum()
```

I get this error:

```
  report["NUM"] =  (~dataset['NUM'].apply(luhn)).sum()
C:\Users\Oleh\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17284\2678582562.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: please provide a minimal example of `dataset`

Comment: and what is `isValid`? and the expected output?

Comment: Most certainly a duplicate. With the given info, try: `report = dataset[dataset['NUM'].apply(isValid) == False]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the rows where `isValid` outputs False:

```
(~dataset['NUM'].apply(isValid)).sum()
```

output: `0`

##### edit

```
m = dataset['NUM'].apply(isValid)
report["NUM"] = (~m).sum()
dataset2 = dataset[m]
```

Comment: How to update current dataframe with valid values?

Comment: what is the expected output? Also in your example you use a different dataframe

Comment: And why not count() ?

Comment: I expect the same frame excluding rows where column `NUM` is False

Comment: `count` returns the number of non-null rows. Please read the documentation. Also [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: If you want to filter, no need to count: use `out = dataset[dataset['NUM'].apply(isValid)]`

Comment: I need to to filter and count at the same time

Comment: You can't do *at the same time*, but you can do both (just save `dataset['NUM'].apply(isValid)` in a variable and reuse it). Once again, it would help to provide the exact expected output.

Comment: Why I got error in this line when I try to count duplicates `NUM` in `invalidatedNumsDb`:

`report['ccunm_dup_db']= [dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)].sum()`

Comment: What is `report`? What is your expected output?

Comment: report is it is dict python with keys it should contain number of wrong number

Comment: I provided the full code for clarity

Comment: What is the output of `type(report)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
dataset[dataset['NUM'].map(isValid) == False].count()
```

Because

```
dataset['NUM'].apply(~isValid)
```

is just wrong.

isValid is a function, ~isValid is like not isValid, which I'm guessing evaluates to False? I'm not sure.

Also

```
dataset[col].apply(func)
```

will return the whole dataset with the values returned by the function for each row. If you want to filter out the False ones you need the

```
 df[df[col]==True]
```

syntax. If you had a new column say

```
df["valid"] =  dataset[col].map(func)
```

You could then do

```
df.query("valid is False")
```

Or something of the sort

Answer (score -1):

```
def isValid(value):
   return True

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'NUM':[1,2,3], 'AGE':[18,19,20], 'COUNTRY':['USA','USA','AU']})

report = {'wrong_rows':(~my_df.NUM.apply(isValid)).sum()}
```

Comment: Thank you how to update a current dataframe?

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.